# Configure OmniAuth logger to two different loggers depending the level of the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, omniauth

In my Rails 5 app I have `'omniauth', '~> 2.0.3'` where in my config  `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` I'm attaching the logger to the `Rails.logger`.

`OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger`

What I want to do is if the log level is `error` I want to use Rollbar instead of the Rails logger.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a proxy logger which delegate `error` level logs to `Rollbar`, other levels will delegate to `Rails.logger`

```rb
class ProxyLogger
  delegate :error, to: :@error_logger
  delegate_missing_to :@default_logger

  def initialize(error_logger:, default_logger: Rails.logger)
    @default_logger = default_logger
    @error_logger = error_logger
  end
end

OmniAuth.config.logger = ProxyLogger.new(error_logger: Rollbar)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems cool but a got a `.../omniauth.rb:6: warning: circular argument reference - error_logger`. Line 6 being `def initialize...` . Could this be dangerous?

Comment: @saralance according to RuboCop that is bad, i updated my answer,